# solving a singular matrix

Tags: matrix, eigen, finite-element-analysis, singular, unwrap

I am trying to write a little unwrapper for meshes. This uses a finite-element-method to solve for minimal linear stress between flattened and the raw  surface. At the moment there are some vertices pinned to get a result. Without this the triangles are rotated and translated randomly...

But as this pinning isn't necessary for the problem, the better solution would be to directly solve the singular matrix. Petsc does provide some methodes to solve a singular system by providing some information on the nullspace. http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manual.pdf#section.4.6 I wonder if there is any alternative for this in Eigen. If not, are there any other possibilities to solve this problem without fixing/pinning vertices.

thanks,
nice regards

see also this link for further informaton:
[dev history](http://forum.freecadweb.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=18010)

Comment: If the null space is analytically known, then you can try to write a custom preconditionner that woud be a projector designed to eliminate rigid movements. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980074/how-to-use-custom-preconditioner-with-eigen and https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/1a24287c6c133b46f8929cf5a4550e270ab66025/Eigen/src/IterativeLinearSolvers/BasicPreconditioners.h?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#BasicPreconditioners.h-185 Take a look at http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/7488/null-space-projection-for-singular-systems

Answer (score 1):

Eigen provides an algorithm for SVD decomposition: [Jacobi SVD](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1JacobiSVD.html).

The SVD decomposition gives the null-space. Following the notations of the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition), let `M = U D V` be the SVD decomposition of M, where `D` is a diagonal matrix of the singular values. Then, from the [Range, null space and rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Applications_of_the_SVD):

> The right-singular vectors [V] corresponding to vanishing singular values of M span the null space of M

Comment: I think SVD isn't that suited for bigger matrices. I would like to use the conjugate-gradient solver.

Comment: SVD is a rather time-consuming decomposition but the implementation in Eigen in very reliable (regarding numerical precision). What matrix size do you target ?

Comment: You can also have a look at `PartialPivLU` and `FullPivLU` classes which can give you the kernel. http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicLinearAlgebraDecompositions.html

Comment: I think the matrix could get up to 10^6 x 10^6 but is very sparse and symmetric. It is a iterative procedure, where  I use the last result as guess for the next linear solution.

Comment: I use now a lagrange multiplier for all 3 dofs (2 translation one rotation). So this constraints the total x translation, total y translation and total rotation. This works quite good. But I am still looking for answers how to project the nullspace solution from the rhs.